# How can one access completed docs in docusign if the document was signed using Docusign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I signed a document using docusign API as a recipient but I am not able to see any completed documents in my docusign account. I can access the signed document through the mail I received from docusign after signing. Is there any way to view it in the completed documents dashboard in docusign ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there's no exact match between the full name + email that was used when you were sent a document to what is in your account.
In order for DocuSign to know when someone send you an envelope that it should go to your account, the full name (case sensitive!) as well as the email must match *exactly* to what is in the DocuSign account. Even then, you need to log into DocuSign to associate the envelope you received with your account.

Comment: The full name and email I used when sending the envelope is the same as in Docusign account. But still I'm not able to view them in the completed documents dashboard.